# Select duplicate row from SQL Server based on multiple filter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this data

```
ID Name State Check
1  Raj  UP     ok
1  Raj  UP     Notok
2  bob  MP     ok
2  bob  MP     ok
3  joy  MH     Notok
3  joy  MH     Notok
```

I want following data

```
ID Name State Check  flag
1  Raj  UP     ok      y  
1  Raj  UP     Notok   n 
2  bob  MP     ok      y
2  bob  MP     ok      n
3  joy  MH     Notok   y
3  joy  MH     Notok   n
```

I want to identify which was selected.

Comment: And "selected" means ...

Comment: Completely different question after last edit... Somewhat disrespectful to whose who've answered already.

Answer (score 2):

You should specify the rules, but it looks like any `ok` makes the name `ok`:

```
select id, name, state,
       (case when sum(case when [check] = 'ok' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
             then 'ok'
             else 'Notok'
        end) as [check]
from t
group by id, name, state;
```

Note:  `check` is a keyword in SQL so it is a bad name for a column.  In your case, you could also do:

```
select id, name, state, min(lower([check])) as [check]
from t
group by id, name, state;
```

This version uses the alphabetic ordering of the values for the logic.

Comment: but the check value can be in any order

Comment: @Rahul . . . I don't understand your comment.

Comment: I'd do `max(lower([check]))`, to avoid casing issues.

Comment: I have update the question might be help to udenstand my prob

Comment: I have update the question might be help to udenstand my prob

Comment: @Rahul . . . It is rude to change a question after it has been answered.  The changes can invalidate answers, and that can draw downvotes.  The proper course of action is to ask another question, if the first question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #Temp (ID int, Name Varchar(8000), State char(2), [Check] varchar(8000))
Insert #Temp Values (1,  'Raj',  'UP',     'ok')
Insert #Temp Values (1  ,'Raj',  'UP',     'Notok')
Insert #Temp Values (2  ,'bob',  'MP',     'ok')
Insert #Temp Values (2  ,'bob',  'MP',     'ok')
Insert #Temp Values (3  ,'joy',  'MH',     'Notok')
Insert #Temp Values (3  ,'joy',  'MH',     'Notok')


;With cteRowsAssigned AS
(
Select  Row_Number() Over (Partition By Name Order By [Check] Desc) RowNum,
        *
    From #Temp
)
Select ID, Name, State, [Check] From cteRowsAssigned Where RowNum = 1 Order By ID
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean `ok` takes precedence on `Notok`

```
select id, name, state, case when max(
       case when [check] = 'ok' then 1 else 0 end) = 1
       then 'ok'
       else 'Notok'
    end as [check]
from table
group by id, name, state;
```

Comment: I have update the question might be help to udenstand my prob

Answer (score 0):

Simplest form would be:

```
SELECT id,name,state FROM t where <whatever filter you want to set> GROUP BY id,name,state
```